# Blazor server with AzureB2c always redirect to AzureADB2C/Account/Error when trying to signin

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm setting up a new blazor server side hosted project. Through the visual studio template, I've configured AzureB2C individual accounts. I have successfully created the app registrations and added two identity providers. By e-mail and Microsoft Accounts.

When pushing on the sign-in button in the default demo app, it goes to the sign-in page and directly redirects to my localhost site. But instead of being signed in, I'm constantly send to http://localhost:port/AzureADB2C/Account/Error.

Since I don't receive any other information or exception on this, it seems impossible to me to resolve this.

What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

**Edit 1**

I found some useful output in the visual studio debug output window

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Error: Message contains error: 'unauthorized_client', error_description: 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the OAuth Implicit flow.
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking several days into this matter, some things are important to know.

- If you are trying to test the 'Microsoft Identity Provider' for localhost debugging and deploy, it won't work. See the error of image 3. In this case, I've enabled the individual user accounts (emails) identity provider to test with.
- If you're redirected to the error page of your blazor application, there will likely be an error/exception in the visual studio output window

For the case as described in this question, I found an exception in the output window of visual studio:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Error: Message contains error: 'unauthorized_client', error_description: 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the OAuth Implicit flow.
```

This means some settings need to be modified in Azure.

- On the Azure AD B2C application page for your application: set 'Allow Implicit Flow' to yes
- On the Azure App Registrations page for your application: check if the "Access Tokens" is checked.
- Restart the debugging of your application in Visual Studio if needed. It will work a couple of minutes later

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This drove me crazy!

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to avoid implicit, but... See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563293/why-does-blazor-net-server-visual-studio-2019-set-up-aad-b2c-to-use-oauth-impli

Comment: This was critical! Thanks!