# Why does Blazor.net Server, Visual Studio 2019 set up AAD B2C to use OAuth implicit flow but recommends against it?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I set up a new Blazor.NET project in Visual Studio 2019 (preview 5) and add Azure AD B2C (AADB2C) and deploy it to an Azure Docker AppService.

If I don't enable OAuth2 implicit flow in AADB2C, then I get the following error using an AADB2C V2 Sign-In-Flow:

```
error=unauthorized_client&error_description=AADB2C90057%3A+The+provided+application+is+not+configured+to+allow+the+%27OAuth%27+Implicit+flow.
```

However, the AADB2C site advises against using this flow unless required for serverless SPA. It recommends MSAL. However, I do have a single ASP.NET-Core 3.1 server. So what can I use instead of the implicit flow? (pointers?) or why is the implicit flow still required/best?

Comment: Because it currently is the only one that works.  I have spent hours trying to figure this out myself.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/MSAL-browser-B2C-CORS-issue

"A fix for the issue is currently being prioritized, please bear with us. We anticipate a resolution by the end of August.

In the meantime, while we work on the fix and any temporary workarounds, please continue to use the implicit flow and Web platform type with B2C applications."

Comment: Thanks. This answers it.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor is a single-page application so you can use implicit flow, it is recommended that you enable implicit flow.

Compared with other authorizations, implicit authorization has more risks, mainly because it enables applications that execute active code and is provided to the browser by remote resources. If you are planning a SPA architecture, do not set up back-end components or try to call Web APIs through JavaScript, but use implicit streams to obtain tokens.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, and still trying to thoroughly understand this. Blazor Server uses a SignalR-stream to originating host-server. So it is  not a classical SPA+JS via REST. In this case, I'm not using 3rd party APIs. What do you mean by "implicit streams" pointer?

Comment: @GGleGrand Sorry, my wording is wrong, it should be  "implicit flow"

Comment: @GGleGrand If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated, but doesn't really answer my question since Blazor Server is not a classical SPA design.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I must be missing something, but it seems like as long as this is hardcoded in [AzureAdB2COpenIDConnectEventHandlers.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Azure/AzureAD/Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/src/AzureAdB2COpenIDConnectEventHandlers.cs#L36):

```
context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
```

that implicit is the only OIDC flow possible with Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI.  In theory it should be possible to override that, maybe something like this?

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(oidcOptions => 
        oidcOptions.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = CustomRedirectToIdentityProviderDelegate);
```

But I don't know what else would have to change.  Also, I too would like to know why this is the way it is.

Comment: Thanks. Here, it looks like this OpenId is (re)set if the DefaultPolicy is not being used. The Defaults.AuthenticationScheme is "AzureADB2C" which looks similar to OpenId (server-side /singin-oidc callback) but svr-side required?. This is probably quite safe in blazor-server with signalR/sever-pages but is still not the Authorization Code Flow (Authorization Code grant) flow I'm looking for. oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit

Comment: Looks like Auth Code Flow is available via MSAL as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/